# Wrapper Application to start and stop an application on android remotely

Tags: android

So I need some help. I am newly learning android development and I need to create a wrapper app so I can start and stop a pre-installed app on my android phone remotely and stop it as well. Is this possible? How long would you think this will take. Also, I am not sure where to start exactly so if any of you can give any hints or links to tutorials or advice in general it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "start... a pre-installed app"? 2. What do you mean by "stop a pre-installed app"? 3. What do you mean by "remotely"? Please be very precise in your answers.

Comment: By start I mean that the application should run and stop is it should stop executing. I wish to have an application that I've programmed onto my phone where I can turn on another application through it from perhaps my computer at home without doing any physical activity on the phone. For example, suppose I want to start playing music on my phone, then through my wrapper app, i should be able to play the music on the phone by connecting to the wrapper app through my computer which turns on my music player on the phone. I hope this clarifies things...

Comment: First, you do not "stop a pre-installed app" on Android -- you do not "stop" *any* app on Android, in any generic fashion. Second, you apparently do not want to just "start... a pre-installed app", but rather "start... a pre-installed app and then perform arbitrary operations upon that app programmatically, such as pressing the 'play' button of a music player". Fortunately, that is not supported, for obvious security reasons. Third, unless you are a security expert, "connecting to the wrapper app through my computer" also means that script kiddies worldwide can do the same to your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Well I might be answering to late to your question ,  but I was trying to do the same, and then searched for lot of answers, found your post and decided to reply what I found.

The Following source code is source code for an app that can help you to manage your applications in the background. 
https://github.com/ndagrawal/android-autostarts

This application does help to start our application at the startup and stop other applications after the bootup process that is at the start .

Following is the link where I got the answer: 
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/how-can-i-stop-applications-and-services-from-running